# Как защитить админку сайта?

Tags: .htaccess, php, администрирование, mysql

Как защитить админку сайта? Использовал `htaccess` и `.htpasswd`.

Вот что я писал в `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter your login and password"
AuthUserFile htpasswd/.htpasswd
Require admin
```

В `.htpasswd` специальной программкой зашифровал пароль. Но тут проблема. Либо бьет 500 ошибку, либо просто не пускает на сайт выводя белый экран.

Отсюда вопрос, как защитить админку сайта? Используя `.htaccess` и `.htpasswd` или расскажите, если у кого-то есть на примете другие способы защиты.

Я слышал что как-то можно защищать через базы mysql - но как я точно не знаю, к сожалению.

Comment: при удачном входе и логином админа создавай сессию, на других адм. страницах редирект тех кто без сесии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Можно через базу и `Mysql`. Могу выслать готовый скрипт

В базе есть таблица с администраторами:

> id | login | pass

`php`:

```
<?php
function if_admin($login, $pass){ // проверяет пользователя, является ли он администратором
    if(!mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass")) // подключение в БД
          die('Ошибка при подключении к базе данных #1'); //ошибка 1 - ошибка подключения
    elseif(!mysql_select_db("database"))
          die('Ошибка при подключении к базе данных #2'); //ошибка 2 - ошибка выбора базы данных
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='".$login."'"));
    if($result){
        if($result['pass'] == md5($pass)){
            return true;
        }
    } 
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

if(if_admin($_GET['login'], $_GET['pass'])){
    echo "Вы вошли";
}
else{
    echo "попробйте ещё раз";
}

?>
```

`mysql`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admins` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Чтобы войти, нужно сделать следующий запрос по `URL`:

```
page.php?login=LOGIN&pass=PASSWORD
```

Слова, написанные в верхнем регистре нужно заменить. В базу пароль нужно записывать в md5.

Comment: буду очень благодарен! Пришлите пожалуйста. А это случайно не security_mod от softtime?

Comment: Нет. На php и mysql. Будет где-то через час

Comment: К ответу добавил куски кода. Все протестировано на локальном сервере.

Comment: хм, интересный подход. Такая защита исключает возможность попадания в админку по прямой ссылке? тоесть имея ссылку типа simole-site.com/admin/ установив эту авторизацию в папку админ попасть будет нельзя?

Comment: По http://simole-site.com/admin/ в админку не попасть. Но если будет запрос, к примеру http://simole-site.com/admin/?login=admin&pass=1234, и если данные совпадут с данными в базе - тогда вход в админку открыт!

Comment: да, оно работает. Спасибо.

Comment: ...не храните в базе пароли. Храните хэш от пароля, их и сравнивайте

Comment: Тут так и происходит:)

Comment: Ок тогда, смотрел бегло.

Еще доступ к админке только по HTTPS организовать можно

Comment: Сравнение хэша должно быть полным. Оператор `==`, при сравнении хэшей `123…ff` и `145…ab` сравнит только два символа, чем откроет вектор для т.н. [атаки по времени](http://rdist.root.org/2010/01/07/timing-independent-array-comparison/). Атакующий может наблюдать как быстро происходит сравнение и подбирать хэш посимвольно (напоминаю, что задача конструкции MD5-хэша с заданным префиксом считается [простой](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/105)). Сетевые и случайные задержки, при этом, вполне можно исключить отправив тысячи запросов (см. объяснения в пп.1,2 по первой ссылке).